# Tight estimates on the Lovász and Multilinear extensions of a submodular function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, submodularity

I assume here some familiarity with the jargon used in submodular optimization (please let me know if something is unclear).

Let $f:2^V \to \mathbb{R}$ be monotone, normalized and submodular. For any $A \subset V, j \in V$, let $f_{A}(j)$ denote the marginal benefit of adding $j$ to $A$ i.e., $f_{A}(j) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} f(A \cup \{j\})-f(A)$.

We define the curvature $c$ of $f$ as $$c \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\max_{j \in V} \frac{f(\{j\})-f_{V-j}(j)}{f(\{j\})} = 1-\min_{j \in V} \frac{f_{V-j}(j)}{f(\{j\})}$$

This is a measure of how far $f$ is from being modular. It's easy to see that $c=0$ if and only if $f$ is modular. Moreover, always we have $c \in [0,1]$. It's also easy to see that given $A,B \subset V$, we have that $(1-c)f_{A}(j) \leq f_B(j)$. (These facts are supposed to be helpful for the problem I'm about to describe).

Let $f_L, f_M:[0,1]^V \to \mathbb{R}$ respectively denote the Lovász and Multilinear extensions of $f$. It's well-known that $f_L \leq f_M$. The problem is to show $f_M \leq \frac{1}{1-c}f_L$. This yields a tight estimate $f_L \leq f_M \leq \frac{1}{1-c}f_L$.

> Does anyone know of a reference where this is proven? Or can anyone provide a proof (or just an outline)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it well known that $f_L \le f_M$? If you follow the definition of continuous extensions it may help you see the proof. See Dughmi's article. https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0322